# DbSet.Load() method is too slow

Tags: wpf, performance, entity-framework, sqlite, code-first

I have an SQLite database, which contains one table named "Main". Each record of this table contains only two fields: ID (integer, primary key) and name (string). There are 100 records in the database.

Using Entity Framework Power Tools I've created the Code First model from the existing database. The model is  rather simple:

```
// MainMap.cs
public class MainMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Main>
{
    public MainMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Main");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.name).HasColumnName("name");
    }
}

// Main.cs
public partial class Main
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

// mainContext.cs
public partial class mainContext : DbContext
{
    static mainContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<mainContext>(null);
    }

    public mainContext()
        : base("Name=mainContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Main> Mains { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MainMap());
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the records from the database:

```
mainContext context = new mainContext();
context.Mains.Load();
```

Now I can use `context.Mains.Local` with a comfort for different purposes (actually, I bind it to `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`).

The problem is that `context.Main.Load()` line executes for about 2.7 seconds. I think, it is too much time as for retrieving about 100 records from a simple database. Although, I'm a newcomer to databases, so, maybe I'm not right and 2.7 seconds is rather suitable period of time. My CPU is Intel i3-3220 (2x3.30 GHz), Entity Framework's version is 6.0.

Maybe, my Code First model is poor, or maybe EF doesn't provide high performance, or maybe there is no need to call `Load()` method to obtain records (but if I don't call it, `context.Mains.Local` is empty).

So, how can I increase the performance of getting the records from the database?

Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the performance characteristics of the EF SQLite driver. Could you check the generated SQL and see if it's decent? It may just be a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

i ran some tests with both SQLite and SQL Server. on my laptop (corei7 2630QM 2.00GHZ & win7 64bit) the load time for both was ~1.5sec.
then i tried to warm it up with something like

```
context.Database.Exists();
```

and the time reduced to ~700ms for both.

i used "Prefer 32-bit" and "Optimize code" options in build tab of the project properties. these options produced best results.

try these and see if the load time changes.